# How validate many fields in code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, webforms

I have a signup page that have many filed.  Many of them should filled by user.
[image] 
I use `RequiredFieldValidator` and `RegularExpressionValidator` for validate in client side.
Should I validate them in server side? How? 
I wrote this code. I use many if and else if. Is this correct?

```
CaptchaControl1.ValidateCaptcha(txtSecureImg.Text);

if (CaptchaControl1.UserValidated)
{
   if (txtFName.Text != string.Empty && txtLName.Text != string.Empty && txtUserName.Text != string.Empty && txtEmail.Text != string.Empty && txtPass.Text != string.Empty && txtCPass.Text != string.Empty && txtSecureImg.Text != string.Empty)
   {
       if (RegEx.EmailValidate(txtEmail.Text) == 1 && RegEx.PasswordValidate(txtPass.Text) == 1 && RegEx.UserName(txtUserName.Text) == 1)
       {
           try
           {
              // insert in database
           }
           catch (Exception)
           {
              lblMsg.Text = "Error";
           }
       }
       else if(RegEx.EmailValidate(txtEmail.Text) == 0)
       {
        EmailRegularExpression.Visible = true;
       }
       else if(RegEx.PasswordValidate(txtPass.Text) == 0)
       {
        passRegularExpression.Visible = true;
       }
       else if(RegEx.UserName(txtUserName.Text) == 0)
       {
        UnameRegularExpression.Visible = true;
        }
   }
   else if(txtFName.Text == string.Empty)
   {
    RequiredFieldValidator1.Visible = true;
   }
    // continue like above for another filed
}
else
{
    lblMsg.Text = "Please insert Secure Image";
}
```

And :

```
public static int EmailValidate(string Mail)
{
    int i = 0;
    Regex regExEmail = new Regex(@"\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*");
    if (regExEmail.IsMatch(Mail))
        i = 1;
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming this is Web Forms...

The validation is run automatically. You can just use the `Page.IsValid` property: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.isvalid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You'll still need to manually check the captcha field though.

```
CaptchaControl1.ValidateCaptcha(txtSecureImg.Text);

if (CaptchaControl1.UserValidated && Page.IsValid)
{
     // Insert in db.
}
```

Comment: Yes , that is Web Forms. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since you use those validators, then you don't need to validate form in server side again like your codes.

But you should call `Page.Validate()`and then check page with `Page.IsValid` method.

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3547368/2040375)

[example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.isvalid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)